# How to import the android support library for gingerbread API 9?

Tags: java, android

So i've been receiving this error from Android Studio
 it says:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\Users\ASUS.android\build-cache\886b56843583b27d32fb5376ee257ce1046c25e7\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

what i understood is that when creating the project i put API 9 Gingerbread, but then when Android launches my project the "automatic" generated import lines at the top that declare which API i use doesn't match the gingerbread API 9.
My question is can you tell me what is the correct import line i should put to get the appropriate API 9 SDK for my App?

Or if i'm getting this wrong and i want to use API 9, how to fix this?

this is the MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.android.takiacademylaunch;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; //the error should be here
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'`

Version `25.4.0` was the last version to support Android `9` - `13`